# SonarQube not able scan complete python code

Tags: python, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I have python script with around 520 lines of code. But when i am scanning it with sonar qube i could observe that only aroung 390 line of code is getting scanned. Please help me to fix this,

my sonar version:: 5.6.7,
sonar Python plugin verion:: 1.8.0.1496,
mine is windows machine

Below is my sonar property file content::

```
sonar.projectKey=my:python_1
sonar.projectName=python_1
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=py
```

Please find the analysis log as below :-

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-windows\bin\..\conf\sonar-sca
nner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: D:\DELPHI\Python-Scripts\getjirareleaseinfo\sonar-project.pro
perties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\20124457\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load global repositories
INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=369ms
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\20124457\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=41ms
INFO: SonarQube server 5.6.7
INFO: Default locale: "en_IN", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)

INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=129ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=86ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=2119ms
WARN: SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use
sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: -------------  Scan getjirareleaseinfo
INFO: Language is forced to py
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=502ms
INFO: Base dir: D:\<dir1>\<dir2>\getjirareleaseinfo
INFO: Working dir: D:\<dir1>\<dir2>\getjirareleaseinfo\.scannerwork
INFO: Source paths: .
INFO: Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: en_IN
INFO: Index files
INFO: 1 files indexed
INFO: Quality profile for py: Sonar way
INFO: JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : D:\<dir1>\<dir2>\getjirareleaseinfo\target\jac
oco.exec
INFO: JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: D:\<dir1>\<dir2>\getjirareleaseinfo\target
\jacoco-it.exec
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=10ms
INFO: Sensor PythonXUnitSensor
INFO: Sensor PythonXUnitSensor (done) | time=16ms
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
INFO: No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specif
y it.
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=4ms
INFO: Sensor Python Squid Sensor
INFO: Python unit test coverage
INFO: Python integration test coverage
INFO: Python overall test coverage
INFO: Sensor Python Squid Sensor (done) | time=453ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=10ms
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for py
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=35ms
INFO: Calculating CPD for 1 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 60ms, dir size=101 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 19ms, zip size=28 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 121ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/my:getjirareleaseinf
o1
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the s
ubmitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWHVtRKYC92AFUo5IKT6
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 8.724s
INFO: Final Memory: 46M/227M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the parts of your analysis log that relate to exclusions and how many/which files are being picked up by analysis, as well as any other parts that may seem relevant.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam
I have added the analysis log in above, but there are no exclusions in that.

Comment: SonarQube makes a distinction between "lines" and "lines of code". Some lines have no code because they are blank or only contain comments. Does that explain what you see?